# JSP validate user is coming from previous page

Tags: java, http, jsp, reference, spoofing

In my JSP webapp, i want to validate that a user is coming from a specific page of mine, `http://myapplication.com/foo.jsp`. On the page doing the checking, I could do:

```
String ref = request.getHeader("referer");
```

Then compare `ref` to `http://myapplication.com/foo.jsp`

However, this validation can be easily spoofed. What are some other techniques to verify that a client is coming from an expected URL?

I imagine this has come up before in SO.
Thanks

PR

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let the preprocessing servlet of the first JSP generate an unique token.

```
String token = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
```

---

Store this in session

```
session.setAttribute("token", token);
```

---

Pass it as hidden input value of the form

```
<input type="hidden" name="token" value="${token}" />
```

or as a request parameter of the link when you're using links instead of forms

```
<a href="second.jsp?token=${token}">link</a>
```

---

Let the preprocessing servlet of the second JSP compare it with the one in the session

```
String token = (String) session.getAttribute("token");
session.removeAttribute("token");

if (token != null && token.equals(request.getParameter("token"))) {
    // Valid, continue requesst.
} else {
    // Invalid, block request.
}
```

---

That was the basic concept which assumes a single page-to-page conversation. To cover multiple browser pages/tabs you'd like to use `Set<String>` or maybe `Map<String, Set<String>>` as token instead (with URIs as keys and tokens as values).

Answer (score 0):

The only way to really make sure is to store the "last page visited" in the session.  That way it doesn't get transmitted to the client, or possibly spoofed by the head of a request.

The idea is that in the jsp being returned, it updates the "last page visited" property in the current session.  Then in the early processing of a page, a check against the "last
 page visited" property is made.

Of course, this doesn't work between web servers unless they are configured to share session information.